# Ember inline if gives error TypeError: options.template is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

If I do

```
{{#each pages as |page|}}
   {{#if (eq page actual)}}
     <li class="active"><a href="#">{{page}}</a></li>
   {{else}}
     <li><a href="#">{{page}}</a></li>
   {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
```

It works well, but it is too repetitive...

I wanna make an inline if like this:

```
{{#each pages as |page|}}
    <li {{if (eq page actual) "class='active'"}}><a href="#">{{page}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

But this gives the following error:

```
TypeError: options.template is undefined
```

Which I couldn't find anywhere. The closest topic I found was [this one](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14074), but it is not what I want...

My `eq` helper is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const eq = (params) => params[0] === params[1];
export default Ember.Helper.helper(eq);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to do that would be to use this for the list tag:

```
<li class={{if (eq page actual) "active"}}><a href='#'>{{page}}</a></li>
```

Does that help? If not, that error message doesn't seem to have a lot to do with this section of your template.

Comment: Yes, it fixed the problem. Thank you!